# Select all checkboxes in closest div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to get this to work from other posts, but keep running into a wall.

I have an "All" button, that I'd like select all or unselect all in the closest div class of "apply_all"

I'm trying to make this work with a long set of appended divs

```js
        $(document).on('change', '.applyallsearches', (function() {
        var applyallchecks = $(this).closest('.applyall');
          if (this.checked) {
           applyallchecks.find('input:checkbox').attr('checked'); 
          } else { 
           applyallchecks.find('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
          }
      })
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pet_selection">    
Select pets<BR>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="applyallsearches" value="all">All
    </div>
    <div class="applyall">
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="1">Pet 1<BR>
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="2">Pet 2<BR>
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="3">Pet 3<BR>
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="4">Pet 4<BR>
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="5">Pet 5<BR>
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="6">Pet 6<BR>
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="7">Pet 7<BR>
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="8">Pet 8<BR>
    </div>
    
    <BR>Select pets<BR>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="applyallsearches" value="all">All
    </div>
    <div class="applyall">
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="1">Pet 1<BR>
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="2">Pet 2<BR>
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="3">Pet 3<BR>
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="4">Pet 4<BR>
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="5">Pet 5<BR>
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="6">Pet 6<BR>
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="7">Pet 7<BR>
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="8">Pet 8<BR>
    </div>
    
    <BR>Select pets<BR>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="applyallsearches" value="all">All
    </div>
    <div class="applyall">
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="1">Pet 1<BR>
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="2">Pet 2<BR>
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="3">Pet 3<BR>
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="4">Pet 4<BR>
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="5">Pet 5<BR>
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="6">Pet 6<BR>
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="7">Pet 7<BR>
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="8">Pet 8<BR>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `closest()` searches up the DOM though the parent nodes.  `applyall` is not a parent node.  It is the next sibling from the parent node of the checkbox.  From the checkbox, you have to go up to the div, and over to the next div to reach `applyall`.  http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Comment: Do you want to modify your markup or your script?

Comment: Please don't post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. Just include your code in a "code snippet" and it will be executable right here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: (this will work even for appended divs also)

```js
$(document).on('change', '.applyallsearches', function() {
          var applyallchecks = $(this).parents('.search-sec').find('[name="apply_all"]');
          if (this.checked) {
           applyallchecks.prop('checked','checked'); 
          } else { 
           applyallchecks.removeAttr('checked');
          }
      })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Select pets<BR>
  <div class="search-sec">
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="applyallsearches" value="all">All
    </div>
    <div class="applyall">
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="1">Pet 1<BR>
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="2">Pet 2<BR>
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="3">Pet 3<BR>
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="4">Pet 4<BR>
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="5">Pet 5<BR>
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="6">Pet 6<BR>
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="7">Pet 7<BR>
      <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="8">Pet 8<BR>
    </div>
  </div>
    
    <BR>Select pets<BR>
    <div class="search-sec">
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" class="applyallsearches" value="all">All
      </div>
      <div class="applyall">
        <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="1">Pet 1<BR>
        <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="2">Pet 2<BR>
        <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="3">Pet 3<BR>
        <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="4">Pet 4<BR>
        <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="5">Pet 5<BR>
        <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="6">Pet 6<BR>
        <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="7">Pet 7<BR>
        <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="8">Pet 8<BR>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <BR>Select pets<BR>
    <div class="search-sec">
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" class="applyallsearches" value="all">All
      </div>
      <div class="applyall">
        <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="1">Pet 1<BR>
        <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="2">Pet 2<BR>
        <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="3">Pet 3<BR>
        <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="4">Pet 4<BR>
        <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="5">Pet 5<BR>
        <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="6">Pet 6<BR>
        <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="7">Pet 7<BR>
        <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="8">Pet 8<BR>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: Your if else can be shortened to just `applyallchecks.prop('checked',this.checked);`

Answer (score 5):

You can go up with the function [`$.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and then find the next siblings using the function [`$.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to select the desired checkboxes.

```js
//Event delegation
$(document).on('change', '.applyallsearches', function() {
  $(this).closest('div')
    .next('div.applyall')
    .find('[name="apply_all"]')
    .prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>Select pets<BR><div>  <input type="checkbox" class="applyallsearches" value="all">All</div><div class="applyall">  <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="1">Pet 1<BR>  <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="2">Pet 2<BR>  <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="3">Pet 3<BR>  <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="4">Pet 4<BR>  <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="5">Pet 5<BR>  <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="6">Pet 6<BR>  <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="7">Pet 7<BR>  <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="8">Pet 8<BR></div><BR>Select pets<BR><div>  <input type="checkbox" class="applyallsearches" value="all">All</div><div class="applyall">  <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="1">Pet 1<BR>  <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="2">Pet 2<BR>  <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="3">Pet 3<BR>  <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="4">Pet 4<BR>  <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="5">Pet 5<BR>  <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="6">Pet 6<BR>  <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="7">Pet 7<BR>  <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="8">Pet 8<BR></div><BR>Select pets<BR><div>  <input type="checkbox" class="applyallsearches" value="all">All</div><div class="applyall">  <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="1">Pet 1<BR>  <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="2">Pet 2<BR>  <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="3">Pet 3<BR>  <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="4">Pet 4<BR>  <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="5">Pet 5<BR>  <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="6">Pet 6<BR>  <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="7">Pet 7<BR>  <input type="checkbox" name="apply_all" value="8">Pet 8<BR></div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  This won't work for appended divs though right?

Comment: @user749798 for later appended elements, you need to use event-delegation.